# Get column name from a table's dataset in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra

I am trying to get the columns from a table

```
 query = session.prepare("""  SELECT * FROM mytable   """)

 row_data = session.execute(query, )
```

What I want is to get the column name from row_data.
Is there a way to do this?.

Comment: Which DB API are you using? Most DB APIs allow some form of "named cursor"

Comment: Okay - which python lib are you using to access it?

Comment: Cassandra'sown lib cassandra.cluster..Is there a way to get the tables metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get like this,

```
fields = [ix[0] for ix in cursor.description]
```

[Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql/1.0.10)

> cursor.description  # None initially, list of N tuples that represent
>                                 the N columns in a row after an execute. Only
>                                 contains type and name info, not values.

Answer (score 5):

In most of the python database adapters you can use a `DictCursor` to retrieve records using an interface similar to the Python dictionaries instead of the tuples.

**Using cassandra**:

```
>>> from cassandra.query import dict_factory
>>> session = cluster.connect('mykeyspace')
>>> session.row_factory = dict_factory
>>> rows = session.execute("SELECT name, age FROM users LIMIT 1")
>>> print rows[0]
{u'age': 42, u'name': u'Bob'}
```

**Using psycopg2**:

```
>>> dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
>>> dict_cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES(%s, %s)",
...                  (100, "abc'def"))
>>> dict_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
>>> rec = dict_cur.fetchone()
>>> rec['id']
1
>>> rec['num']
100
>>> rec['data']
"abc'def"
```

**Using MySQLdb**:

```
>>> import MySQLdb 
>>> import MySQLdb.cursors 
>>> myDb = MySQLdb.connect(user='andy47', passwd='password', db='db_name', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
>>> myCurs = myDb.cursor() 
>>> myCurs.execute("SELECT columna, columnb FROM tablea") 
>>> firstRow = myCurs.fetchone() 
{'columna':'first value', 'columnb':'second value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

With cassandra-driver 3.14 you can also get the column names by accessing the _fields parameter of a query results entry.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

session = Cluster().connect('mykeyspace')

rows = session.execute('select * from mytable limit 1')

column_names = rows.one()._fields
```